# Как объединить библиотеки pyrogram и telebot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, pyrogram

Я сегодня написал первого юзербота для автоматической отправки сообщений с определенным интервалом в телеграме. Теперь я бы хотел бы добавить телеграм бота, который помог бы мне управлять юзерботом. Мне нужно, чтобы я мог включать и выключать рассылку. В интернете найти информацию не могу, вот мои попытки:

```
client = Client(name='me_client', api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)
bot = telebot.TeleBot('6459222338:-0')

scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()


async def spamFromAccount():
    global text
    await client.send_message('me', text)

# cрабатывает, когда юзер нажимает на кнопку
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def callback_message(callback):
    global scheduler
    if callback.data == 'yesSpamMessage':
        scheduler.add_job(spamFromAccount, 'interval', seconds=5)
        scheduler.start()
        client.run()
    if callback.data == 'noSpamMessage':
        reply = 'Напиши новый текст для рассылки. После этого повтори команду /spam ↓'
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, reply)


bot.infinity_polling()
```

Я получаю ошибку:

```
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'WorkerThread2'.
```

Как можно обьединить эти библиотеки?

Comment: Зачем отдельный бот если можно управлять user ботом из его же личных сообщений?

Comment: Это как? Что за личные сообщения? Ты имеешь ввиду Сохраненные сообщения?

Comment: [Смотрите входящие сообщения](https://docs.pyrogram.org/start/update) - и потом [Проверяете что сообщение написал администратор](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/types/Message)

Comment: 1 ссылка не работает. Ты имеешь ввиду создать условно отдельную беседу для себя и туда писать команды?

Comment: Обычно для ботов делают отдельные аккаунты с основного пишете боту и второй сам бот. Рабочая ссылка: https://docs.pyrogram.org/start/updates

Answer (score 0):

Если использовать Asyncio, то вот, попробуйте:

```
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient
import telebot
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler

client = TelegramClient('me_client', api_id, api_hash)
bot = telebot.TeleBot('6459222338:-0')

scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(event_loop=asyncio.get_event_loop())


async def spamFromAccount():
    global text
    await client.send_message('me', text)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def callback_message(callback):
    global scheduler
    if callback.data == 'yesSpamMessage':
        scheduler.add_job(spamFromAccount, 'interval', seconds=5)
        scheduler.start()
        client.start()
    if callback.data == 'noSpamMessage':
        reply = 'Напиши новый текст для рассылки. После этого повтори команду /spam ↓'
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, reply)


bot.infinity_polling()
```

Вместо `client.run()`  сделал `client.start()`.